# Connect to a computer behind router in .net

Tags: .net, sockets, nat

We have a client server application which we are developing in .net. We want the server to push data to client. But the client is behind a router (like a home network setup). What are the various options to implement this in .net?

Comment: Belongs on User-Voice: Use of .NET makes no difference, you need a method to allow an inbound socket to connect.

Comment: @Richard:  You mean serverfault?

Comment: @Kyle: For a home network it would be UV, for corporate SF, but question indicated a home network.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the router includes NAT and Firewall, you need to configure the router to allow an inbound connection to be directed to the machine.

Answer (score 2):

@Richard is correct, you're really asking about NAT.  Another option is to have the client connect out to the server and pull in information that way.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to push data to a client behind a router is if the client sets up some [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on his router. Its something you'll generally want to avoid having to help the client configure.

Is it possible the client can instead periodically contact the server to check for data?  In this scenario because the client makes an outbound connection it will be able to pull data back.

Comment: How do IRC programs wok, then? Isn't the server pushing data to client computers?